# Original array not getting updated when changed in referenced variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

For my work, I need to access nested object array. I do not want to access it every time with full path. So I wanted to shorten the reference by assigning the actual  reference to a variable.

I tried to find out existing answers, but didn't get answer for this scenario.

What I have done:
Assigned the reference of array to a variable, modified the referenced value. But the original array is not getting modified.

Below is a demo code for what I want to achieve.

```js
let obj = {
    innerObj1: {
        arr: [2,3,4,5,6]
    }
}

var ref = obj.innerObj1.arr;
console.log(ref);
// output [2,3,4,5,6]

ref = ref.filter(n => n%2 == 0);
console.log(ref);
// output [2,4,6]

//Original obj
console.log(obj.innerObj1.arr)
// output [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: This is because filter method returns a new array and you are overriding it with new value.

Comment: Yes, filter array returns new array, so I am assigning it to referenced variable which is reference of Actual array. So at the end it should modify original array.

Comment: As stated earlier it creates a new array, it means ref variable is not referring to old array anymore. It is referring to new array created by filter method. Please see description of filter method here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Prince, I got the point, so now ref has actually became new array and pointing to some new location. It has nothing to do with original array i.e. obj.innerObj1.arr.

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `filter` method returns a new array and you are overriding it with the new value.

As stated earlier it creates a new array, it means `ref` variable is not referring to old array anymore. It is referring to new array created by `filter` method.

You can simply use for, while or do while loop to resolve your this issue.

I hope it will help you. Please find working example here:

```js
let obj = {
    innerObj1: {
        arr: [2,3,4,5,6]
    }
}

var ref = obj.innerObj1.arr;
console.log(ref);
// output [2,3,4,5,6]

for(let index=0; index < ref.length; index++) {
 if(ref[index] % 2 === 0) {
    ref[index] = ref[index]
  } else{
   ref.splice(index,1);
  }
}
console.log(ref);
// output [2,4,6]

//Original obj
console.log(obj.innerObj1.arr)
// output [2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access specific indices within `ref`:

```
let obj = {
    innerObj1: {
        arr: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
}

const ref = obj.innerObj1.arr;
console.log(ref);
// output [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for(let i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
  ref[i] = ref[i] % 2 == 0;
}

// Original obj
console.log(obj.innerObj1.arr)
// output [true, false, true, false, true]
```

Answer (score 0):

when we do

```js
var ref = obj.innerObj1.arr;
```

we are having a pointer to `obj.innerObj1.arr`
`ref` is reference to array when we do `ref.filter(n => n%2 == 0);`

to get what we want we have to do

```
obj.innerObj1.arr = ref.filter(n => n%2 == 0);
```

Comment: I tried it, it works. But for my actual case the array inside an object which is nested around 6-7 levels (eg. A.B.C.D.E.arr). so instead of writing so long code  every time  I wanted to get it short.